# System.NotSupportedException when Init BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, bitmap, webclient

I receive an array of messages with attachments from the API and create on their basis `Models` for `UserControls`. In model I call `Initial` method for download image in local storage.But if I open dialog(recieve array from the API) as soon as i run the app, I get an error message `System.NotSupportedException in PresentationCore.dll`
 `Additional Information: No pixel format information found.`

Here is code of Model:

Most interesting i have catch on it but still get

```
public class MediaMessageAttachment : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string FullImageURI { get; set; }
        public string VideoURI { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool HasVideo => VideoURI != null;
        public bool HasImage => FullImageURI != null;
        public string Duration { get; set; }
        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get { return isLoading; }
            set
            {
                isLoading = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoading");
            }
        }

        private BitmapImage image;
        private string previewImageURI;
        private bool isLoading;

        public string PreviewImageURI { get { return previewImageURI; } set { previewImageURI = value; RaisePropertyChanged("PreviewImageURI"); Initial(); } }

        public BitmapImage Image
        {
            get { return image; }
            set
            {
                image = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Image");
            }
        }

        public RelayCommand OpenImageCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public MediaMessageAttachment()
        {
            OpenImageCommand = new RelayCommand(() => OpenImage());
        }

        private void OpenImage()
        {
            if (HasImage)
                PopupVM.ShowPopup(FullImageURI);
            else if (HasVideo)
                PopupVM.ShowPopup(VideoURI);
        }
        public async Task Initial()
        {
            IsLoading = true;
            if (!Directory.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\temp"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\temp");
            }
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\temp\\" + PreviewImageURI.Substring(PreviewImageURI.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                if (File.Exists(path))
                    DownloadFileCompleted(null, null);
                else
                {
                    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCompleted);
                    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(PreviewImageURI), path);
                }
            }
        }

        private void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\temp\\" + PreviewImageURI.Substring(PreviewImageURI.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                Image = new BitmapImage();
                Image.BeginInit();
                Image.UriSource = new Uri(path);
                Image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                Image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
                Image.EndInit();
                Image.Freeze();
                IsLoading = false;
            }
            catch (System.NotSupportedException)
            {
                Initial();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a note, if a method returns a Task, it should be awaited, like `await Initial();`. Besides that, you seem to be mixing two asynchronous concepts. When the awaited `DownloadFileTaskAsync` call returns, the file has been downloaded and you can safely access it. You do not need to attach a `DownloadFileCompleted` handler.

Comment: I think I found the problem. Since the images can be repeated, once again I do not download them, but take the already downloaded ones. So the problem is that the method that creates the image does not have time to finish working with the file before this picture is created again for another message (or it is not released at all). You do not know how to wait until the file is "free"?

Comment: It's unclear why you want to download to a file at all. Why not create a BitmapImage directly from the URL?

Comment: I took this code from my popup. Your proposal looks good, but it seems to me that when I change the dialogue and return to it back, I will have to download the images again. But for now I will use your decision. Is this a way to support asynchrony? I use it to open messages before the pictures are downloaded (download spinner).